# White and black spots on indoor plants: cayenne pepper and salad seedling

Tags: indoors, diseases

many of the plants I'm growing indoor are having these white and black tiny spots on leaves. Some of my seedlings are affected by it as well. The underside has mostly small black spots.

[image: Cayenne Pepper Leave]

[image: Underside of cayenne pepper leaf]

[image: Salad Seedling]

From the description I thought it could be powdery mildew, but I'm growing it indoor, there is no cold air and it's fairly dry (~30% humidity). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have finally found the culprit. It's leafhopper damage.

http://www.theplantlady.com/leafhoppers/
https://ask.extension.org/questions/417048

I have never seen them on the plants though. I've killed plenty of fungus gnats, but I didn't see any leafhopper. Unless they look very similar?